# Byte-based and Chracter-based OutputStreams

Tags: java, file, io

I have to make an app generating 10000 integers with random values from 0 to 100000 and write it to a file on the local system. I have to do it in two different ways - with byte stream and with character stream and to compare the sizes of the produced files. The files got out with very strange characters and their size is the same. Is this how it is supposed to be?

**Byte-based stream:**

```
    Random rd = new Random();
    File outFile = new File( "Byte-based Stream.txt" );
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        fos.write(rd.nextInt(100001));
    }

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

**Character-based Stream:**

```
    Random rd = new Random();
    File outFile = new File( "Character-based Stream.txt" );
    FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(outFile);

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        fos.write(rd.nextInt(100001));
    }

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: No, for one thing, I would think are are supposed to see numbers in plain text in the character based version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileOutputStream.write` writes only a [single byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)) out.

Similarly `FileWriter.write` writes only a [single character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(int)) out.

Even though they both take an `int`, they do not write out an `int`. Instead you must use

```
int rn = rd.nextInt( 1000001 );
byte[ ] bytes = new byte[ ] {
    ( byte ) ( ( rn >>>  0 ) & 0xFF ),
    ( byte ) ( ( rn >>>  8 ) & 0xFF ),
    ( byte ) ( ( rn >>> 16 ) & 0xFF ),
    ( byte ) ( ( rn >>> 24 ) & 0xFF )
};
fileos.write( bytes );
```

for `FileOutputStream` and

```
fos.write( Integer.toString( rd.nextInt( 100001 ) ) );
```

for `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

As you refer in the question`FileWriter` writes characters while `FileOutputStream` writes binary files (byte streams).

Everything are bits in the computer indeed, but the encodings. `FileWriter` write characters as human readable encodings, while `FileOutputStream` writes byte streams.

The sizes are the same, because your default encoding should have 32 bits for each character, while integer in java also have 32 bits for each number.

**See also**

**[FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)**

**[FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)**

**[Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)**

**[Comparison of Unicode encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)**

Answer (score 1):

FileWriter is an old utility class using the default platform encoding (= unportable). It seems you have a single byte encoding, hence the same size.

The following

```
PrintWriter fos = new PrintWriter(outFile, "UTF-16LE");
```

should double the size.

BTW the byte versions use the low order byte (`& 0xFF`).